# Adding EditText alongside RadioButton

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a custom `DialogPreference` subclass in which I would like to have a `RadioGroup` with three radio buttons.  The first two are vanilla `RadioButton` components with titles, but for the third I would like to place an `EditText` directly to the right of it so I can enter a custom value when that button is selected.

I have tried putting the third button into a horizontal `LinearLayout` along with the `EditText` but then the third button does not participate in the parent `RadioGroup` anymore.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/lactate_radio"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/lactate_default_value"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/lactate_default_value"/>

        <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/lactate_calibrated_value"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/lactate_calibrated_value" />
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/lactate_custom_value"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/lactate_custom_value"/>

            <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/lactate_custom_value_edit_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Screenshot of custom DialogPreference]

I have also tried adding this `LinearLayout` programmatically but still had the same behavior.  Is there any way to do this, perhaps by explicitly telling the parent `RadioGroup` about the third button or by somehow positioning the `EditText` appropriately without using a horizontal `LinearLayout`?  Otherwise, I think I'll have to write a `RadioButton` subclass which ought to be a real party!

Comment: What about a RelativeLayout then Linear containing the RadioGroup and then just place the EditText next to the third RadioButton based upon its id attribute.

Comment: As `EditText` is totally different view so it can't be `RadioGroup` part. Either you can programmatically `Enable` & `Disable` while the third radio button clicked is the way to go to achieve something like these. Hope you get it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to change your parent layout to `RelativeLayout`. Then give your `RadioGroup`

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

then place your `EditText` next to and aligned with the bottom of the `RadioGroup`. I haven't tried it but something like this should work.

**Update**

I got time to test it. This seems to give the output you are looking for

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/lactate_radio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/lactate_default_value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="lactate_default_value"/>

    <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/lactate_calibrated_value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="lactate_calibrated_value" />
        <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/lactate_custom_value"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="lactate_custom_value"/>
    </RadioGroup>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/lactate_custom_value_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/lactate_radio"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lactate_radio"
            android:text="Test Text" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Note that I also changed some of the `width`s to `wrap_content` so it would fit together. Changing the `orientation` of the `RadioGroup` to vertical eliminates the need for the `LinearLayout`

Comment: It'd be great if there were a way to do this like my original post.  Imagine if someone wanted an `EditText` alongside each `RadioButton` for example.  Regardless, this seems to be a workable solution for my case.  Just waiting to see if someone else comes through with a miracle solution before accepting yours as The Answer. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it would be nice if there was something already built-in for that but AFAIK there isn't. Anyway, you could still do it easily by using `alignToRightOf` in each then using `layout_below` and place each `EditText` below the previous one. You're welcome and I understand waiting to see if you get something better

Comment: @codeMagic, `RelativeLayout` seems to be deprecated by now, has something more straight forward emerged in the years since 2013?

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_height= "wrap_content"
  android:layout_width= "wrap_content"
  android:orientation= "horizontal"
>

 <LinearLayout
   android:layout_height= "wrap_content"
   android:layout_width= "wrap_content"
   android:orientation= "vertical"
 >

<RadioGroup
  <!-- radio buttons code here -->
/>

 </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
   android:layout_height= "wrap_content"
   android:layout_width= "wrap_content"
 >

 <EditText

 <!-- edit text code here -->
     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/id_ofRadioButton"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/id_ofRadioButton"
 />

 </LinearLayout>
```

If you want edit text **along side each** radio button:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_height= "wrap_content"
  android:layout_width= "wrap_content"
  android:orientation= "vertical"
>

 <LinearLayout
   android:layout_height= "wrap_content"
   android:layout_width= "wrap_content"
   android:orientation= "horizontal"
 >

<RadioGroup
  <!-- single radio button code here -->
/>

 <EditText

 <!-- edit text code here -->

 />

 </LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
  android:layout_height= "wrap_content"
  android:layout_width= "wrap_content"
  android:orientation= "vertical"
>

 <LinearLayout
   android:layout_height= "wrap_content"
   android:layout_width= "wrap_content"
   android:orientation= "horizontal"
 >

<RadioGroup
  <!-- single radio button code here -->
/>

 <EditText

 <!-- edit text code here -->

 />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Properties like `android:layout_toRightOf` aren't available with a `LinearLayout`. Also, in your second solution, the `RadioButton`s would be taken out of the `RadioGroup`