# Is it possible to add a LinearLayout inside a RadioGroup?

Tags: android

I want to make a display like this :

[image]

I want the `radiobuttons` to be mutually-exclusive ! So is it possible to add a `LinearLayout` into a `RadioGroup` ?

Comment: i dnt think so, there is workaround you can enable disable layout on radiobutton click keep your edittext in layouts and enable and disable it

Comment: Just about the possibility of adding LinearLayout into RadioGroup, the answer is YES! Since RadioGroup is subclass of LinearLayout (a ViewGroup), you can further add any layout to it.

Answer (score -1):

You could use something like this for placing text and images in a radioGroup:

```
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/rbtnid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:button="@null"
    android:drawablePadding="30dp"
    android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
    android:text="rtext"
    android:gravity="center|right"/>
```

Or try to add EditTexts to your RadioButtons like it is shown here in the selected as best answer [Adding EditText alongside RadioButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17795156/adding-edittext-alongside-radiobutton)

I hope it will help you :)